# Laravel blade not showing content

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to `yield` in one of my `blade` files but it's not working.

This is my `index.blade.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Forum</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,200,300,400" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="/css/bulma.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="/css/all.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    @include('shared.menu.menu')
    @yield('content')
</div>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my `login.blade.php`:

```
@extends('index')
    @section('content')
        @yield('shared.bar.bar')
    @stop
```

So the navigation bar is showing at this point. But the bar is not! When I replace: `@yield('shared.bar.bar')` with `test`, `test` shows up. This is `shared/bar/bar.blade.php`:

```
@section('bar')
<section class="hero is-primary">
    <div class="hero-body">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title">
                test
            </h1>
            <h2 class="subtitle">
                test
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
@stop
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it also possible to pass variables to the bar? So I can show another `title` and `subtitle` on every page?

--EDIT--

```
@section('bar')
<section class="hero is-primary">
    <div class="hero-body">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title">
                {{ $title }}
            </h1>
            <h2 class="subtitle">
                {{ $subtitle }}
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
@stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are showing all of your code, looks like your yield is

```
@yield('shared.bar.bar')
```

And yout section

```
@section('bar')
```

When it should be

```
@section('shared.bar.bar')
```

Or you should change your yield to

```
@yield('bar')
```

Because `@yield` and `@section` are only strings, they are not related to files like `@include`.

And looks like this file is also wrong:

```
@extends('index')

@section('content')
    @yield('shared.bar.bar')
@stop
```

@yield is something you should start using only in your main layout file, because it can get messy and hard and harder to undestand what's happening. So, unless you have a section 'shared.bar.bar' to fill this @yield, you should probably do something like

```
@extends('index')

@section('content')
    <form>
        .... your login form
    </form>
@stop
```

or

```
@extends('index')

@section('content')
    @include('shared.bar.bar')
@stop
```

or

```
@extends('index')

@section('content')
    @include('shared.bar.bar')

    <form>
        .... your login form
    </form>
@stop
```

To have the title changed via section you can also do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
</head>
```

or

```
<h1 class="title">
    @yield('title')
</h1>
```

And your login blade file, you can do

```
@extends('index')

// This will tell the Blade Compiler to replace every 
// occurence of @yield('title')
@section('title')
    User Login
@stop

@section('content')
    @include('shared.bar.bar')

    <form>
        .... your login form
    </form>
@stop
```

Comment: Hi, when I both call them ```bar``` it's still not working. Also when I call them both ```shared.bar.bar```.

Comment: Looks like you have architected them wrongly, take a look at my edit.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I also would like to pass 2 parameters (see my edit above). But that's not possible with ```include```. That's why I use ```yield```.

Comment: Yield if for sections, not variables. You just have to use `view('viewname', ['title' => 'your title'])`;

Comment: I've done it like this: ```@include('shared.bar.bar', array('title'=>'test', 'subtitle' => 'test'))``` thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice! That works too, but in this case yield and section can help too, showing it how in new edit.

Comment: Also a great solution :)